# IBM Liberty Profile: The feature 'websocket-1.0' is not recognized

Tags: websocket, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

Just an initial step to run websocket application on IBM Liberty Profile 8.5.5.5. After did lots of research I found I needed to add a feature on the Liberty server.xml file.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>websocket-1.0</feature>
     ....... 
</featureManager>
```

But as soon as I added that line on the configuration I'm getting a warning that

**The feature 'websocket-1.0' is not recognized**
server.xml  /WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile/servers/defaultServer
line 5  Liberty Profile Configuration Problem

Any thought? Do I needed to add any Jar file for that?

Answer (score 6):

In the 8.5.5.5 or earlier websocket feature is not contained in the downloaded jar. You have to install it from the repository using the following command:

```
featureManager install websocket-1.0 --when-file-exists=ignore
```

see the following page - [Java WebSocket 1.0](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.websocket-1.0).

The 8.5.5.6 version is Java EE 7 compatible and contains webSocket-1.1 feature already built in, so you may download that one.

Comment: For 8.5.5.5 and earlier, you need to use featureManager rather than installUtility: bin/featureManager install websocket-1.0 --when-file-exists=ignore

Comment: @Azquelt thanks, you are correct. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. You makes my day :)

Answer (score 0):

The feature files are in [Liberty Install]/lib/features folder.

However, I don't see websocket-1.0 or websocket-1.1 in Liberty 8.5.5.5

Try to use 8.5.5.6, you should see websocket-1.1.mf

Comment: Above description from Gas was working fine for me. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

For OpenLiberty navigate to **[OpenLiberty Install]/bin** via shell and execute:

```
featureUtility installFeature websocket-1.0 --acceptLicense
```

This will install the missing feature to the folder **[OpenLiberty Install]/lib/features**.